# How do I create an independent copy of an array in Unity?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

> **TL;DR:** I need a way to copy an array with integers, in which the copy will not change the original array, and that will work in Unity.

I am trying to implement the following algorithm: I have an array field with numbers that are editable in the inspector. These numbers indicate the number of enemies of each type to spawn:
`public int[] EnemiesToSpawn;`

And, for example, I set the array to 3 digits, the index of each in the array corresponds to the index of the object in the array with enemy prefabs.

Then, in the function, I randomly generate enemies, each time decreasing the corresponding number in the array by one (if the element integer is 0, another enemy is selected, and if the integer of all elements becomes 0, the spawn function ends execution).

Everything worked well until I needed to have multiple points on the level, each of which would generate enemies independently. What I did: I added another array, into which I copy the values ​​from the first one every time I need to spawn enemies at a new point, and edited this particular second array instead of the original one (simply by assigning the value via "="). Of course it didn't work, I googled it and realized that arrays in C # are stored as references, not values, so the original array was edited as well.

I tried a lot of options that offer for correct copying (such as System.Array.Copy and others), but for some reason none of them worked in Unity.
The only thing I came up with myself was iterating over in a loop and assigning values ​​separately:

```
EnemiesToSpawnCurrent = new int [EnemiesToSpawn.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i <EnemiesToSpawn.Length; i ++)
        {
            EnemiesToSpawnCurrent [i] = i;
        }
```

But, this code also does not work correctly for some reason, the numbers do not correspond to those entered in the inspector (most likely the indexes of the elements do not match).
I will be grateful if you tell me how you can optimally solve this problem.

Comment: You probably ment `EnemiesToSpawnCurrent[i] = EnemiesToSpawn[i];` .. which would make this question basically based on a typo ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option A:

```
int[] a; // original array you want to deep copy
int[] b = new int[a.length]; // your copy

System.Array.Copy(a, b, a.length);
```

Option B:

```
int[] a; // original array you want to deep copy
int[] b = (int[]) a.Clone();
```

edit: in your code, the numbers won't match, because you are assigning them `i`.

```
EnemiesToSpawnCurrent = new int [EnemiesToSpawn.Length];
for (int i = 0; i <EnemiesToSpawn.Length; i ++)
{
    EnemiesToSpawnCurrent [i] = i; // wrong!
}
```

this should work:

```
EnemiesToSpawnCurrent = new int[EnemiesToSpawn.Length];
for (int i = 0; i <EnemiesToSpawn.Length; i ++)
{
    EnemiesToSpawnCurrent[i] = EnemiesToSpawn[i]; // copy each value from original to new Array.
}
```

Explanation: For int Array, this works because Integers are "Value type" and not reference Type. The whole array is Reference Type, so you need to create a new, independent instance. But assigning the values (ints) to the new array will work.

If you however want to copy something like `Player[]` you would need to create deep copies of the Player instances as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found a similar answer in another thread before, but just in case I checked it again. The problem is the same as with my unsuccessful loop: the numbers in the copied array do not match the numbers in the original array (specified in the inspector). Could it be that when copying, the indexes of the numbers are somehow shifted?

Comment: I edited my Post to explain a possible problem with your code. However a deep copy as I proposed it, should contain the exact same values after copying.